# What Are Death Sticks (In Star Wars)

Tags: star-wars, obi-wan-kenobi, attack-of-the-clones

Many many many times throughout the Star Wars movies, games, books, ect... the mention of death sticks appears. 
In Star Wars II: The Attack of the Clones Obi-Wan is asked to buy some from a shady alien in the bar when they are chasing Zam. As far as I can figure out they are a type of drug. However specifically, does anyone know what they do to you? Make you hallucinate, are they a relaxer, do they just make you feel really good? I am curious.

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Death_stick

Comment: You don't want to know about death sticks. * waves hand *. You want to go home and rethink your life.

Comment: I thought it was an obvious and very heavy handed PSA from Lucas to kids that smoking is bad.

Comment: @Christopher - you should make that into an answer.

Comment: @DVK not a problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The aptly named 'Death Stick' is a mild hallucinogen developed by the Collective Commerce District (CoCo) medical facilities.  They are highly addictive and the cilona extract shortens the users lifespan with each successive dose.

[image: Death Stick]

As well as offering a warped version of reality and making bright lights dance to the beat of Coruscant night club music they are unique in that they reduce the individuals connection with the force, making this guy possibly the dumbest drug dealer in the galaxy (he also tried selling Rancor nail blades to Jango Fett not two days earlier).

[image]

Death Sticks are taken either by mixing with a drink, intravenous injection or by smoking the more potent granulated variety. Treatment for addiction can be found at any good medical centre but it can be very expensive.

Source: [Star wars wikia: Death Stick](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Death_stick)

Comment: You may want to clarify this to indicate which detail is sourced from which level of canon